# Java TLS 1.2 with client authentication error openjdk 1.8

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, tls1.2, resttemplate

When I try to call restTemplate with client authentication I get this following error during ssl handshake.
java -version on my linux platform
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-b08)

Can anybody help me to solve this or at least find right way to look at this issue?

```
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:696)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:662)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:613)
        at cz.trask.ecom.acs2.threedsecure.inte.tm.client.ThreadSecurityLevelCsasConnector.doExchange(ThreadSecurityLevelCsasConnector.java:101)
        ... 316 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: No supported CertificateVerify signature algorithm for RSA  key
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:311)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
        at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateVerify$T12CertificateVerifyMessage.<init>(CertificateVerify.java:597)
        at sun.security.ssl.CertificateVerify$T12CertificateVerifyProducer.produce(CertificateVerify.java:760)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my Key implmentation class needs to imlement Length interface. So TLS handshake is able to determine key sun.security.util.Length. It is so odd that such change occured in jdk patch.